# Inspecting Certificate gives me question mark symbol

Tags: java, android, security, keystore, vpn

I am trying to read a private key entry of a PKCS12 file in order to get a VPN connection working in Android.

This is my code:

```
        String password = "password";
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/Download/certfile.p12"), password.toCharArray());
        Enumeration<String> aliases = keystore.aliases();
        Log.d("key", aliases.nextElement());
```

Now in my Aliases I see the private key Entry with an Alias which seems to contain invalid characters. Because it's showing me in Debug Inspection and also in the console "ALIAS��"

This makes it impossible to load the Alias or check if the keystore contains it.

When I inspect the keystore with the command line with the keytool I get the Aliasname "alias" in small letters.

Comment: How are you setting the alias ? Through code or through some tool...?

Comment: Also the title of the question should be changed...

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee The alias has been set by my company, since they offered the certificates.